# Strange conflict between get postback control and RegisterStartupScript

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, registerstartupscript

Please consider this scenario:

I have a simple page and I want to log all controls causing postback. I create this simple page. It contains a grid to show some URLs and when user click on an icon a new tab should open:

[image]

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #b7ffbb; text-align: center;" colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Click Me First" Height="55px" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #f1d8fe; text-align: center;" colspan="2">
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BackColor="White" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SiteAddress" HeaderText="Address" />
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="~/download.png" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SiteAddress") %>' CommandName="GoTo" Height="32px" Width="32px" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

and code behind:

```
public partial class WebForm2 : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Address> Addresses = new List<Address>()
        {
            new Address(){ SiteAddress = "https://google.com" },
            new Address(){ SiteAddress = "https://yahoo.com" },
            new Address(){ SiteAddress = "https://stackoverflow.com" },
            new Address(){ SiteAddress = "https://learn.microsoft.com/}" }
        };

        GridView1.DataSource = Addresses;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "MyScript", "window.open('" + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "', '_blank')", true);
    }
}

class Address
{
    public string SiteAddress { get; set; }
}
```

every thing is fine till here. Now I create a base class for all of my pages and add below codes for finding postback control:

```
public class MyPageBaseClass : Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            
        }
        else
        {
            var ControlId = GetPostBackControlName();   <------
            //Log ControlId 
        }
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    private string GetPostBackControlName()
    {
        Control control = null;

        string ctrlname = Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
        if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != String.Empty)
        {
            control = Page.FindControl(ctrlname);
        }

        else
        {
            foreach (string ctl in Page.Request.Form)
            {
                Control c;
                if (ctl.EndsWith(".x") || ctl.EndsWith(".y"))
                {
                    string ctrlStr = ctl.Substring(0, ctl.Length - 2);
                    c = Page.FindControl(ctrlStr);
                }
                else
                {
                    c = Page.FindControl(ctl);
                }
                if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button ||
                         c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)
                {
                    control = c;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        if (control != null)
            return control.ID;
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

and change this line:

```
public partial class WebForm2 : MyPageBaseClass
```

Now when I click on icons grid view disappears...(**STRANGE...**) and nothing happened. When I comment specified line then every thing will be fine...(**STRANGE...**).

In `GetPostBackControlName` nothings changed to `Request` but I don't know why this happened. I checked and I see if I haven't `RegisterStartupScript` in click event every thing is fine. Please help we to solve this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to `OnInit` event. I replaced it with `OnPreLoad` and every things is fine now.

For search engines: `OnInit` event has conflict with `RegisterStartupScript`

Answer (score 2):

> when I click on icons grid view disappears...

ASP.Net page class object instances only live long enough to serve one HTTP request, and each HTTP request rebuilds the *entire page* by default.

Every time you do a postback, you have a new HTTP request and therefore a new page class object instance and a completely new HTML DOM in the browser. Any work you've done for a previous instance of the page class — such as bind a list of addresses to a grid — no longer exists.

You *could* fix this by also rebuilding your grid code on each postback, but what I'd really do is skip the whole "RegisterStartupScript" mess and instead make the grid links open the window directly, without a postback at all.

Comment: Sorry can you explain more? I click on the icon and one `Request` will generate. I use that `Request` and there isn't another `HTTP` request?

Comment: Is this solvable?

Comment: When you click on an address in the grid, that's also a postback, which is a new HTTP request and a new object instance.

Comment: Dear friend let's move on step by step please. We are agree about when a postback occures a new page class instance cwill create. I don't do any thing with any request and I just extract `__EVENTARGS` from it. Why when I do this conflict occurs?

Comment: Dear @JoelCoehoorn I use `RegisterStartupScript` for injecting some `JS` and this is a very simple sample to show the conflict. In real life I didn't use that for redirecting

Comment: I don't know why existence of `GetPostBackControlName` is problematic. Consider I have a function that calculate `2*2` in that place. this time this new function isn't problematic... . I hope I have conveyed what I mean....

Comment: I agree with you that every time of a request generated a new instance of page will generate. But what is the relation between this and register startup script? If I change that line in 'RowCommand' with 'int i = 1' every things will be fine...

Comment: A new page class instance on the new http request means new html sent to the browser to replace the old html, even if you don't do anything.